# GPS traking (draw line as the user move on google map)

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gps

I'm trying to to display google map and draw a line as the user walk (Gps traking app)
I've 2 problems:
1- the map doesn't show up (only the grid of the map shows)
2-I'm saving the Geopoints in a list as the user walk (and i can actually see the dot indicating my location on the map moves!) but no line is drawn connecting them.
Could you check my code below and advice?

extra Q: do I have to write Myoverly on a separate java file cause at the moment I have one file with this code on? is it necessiry to choose google api instead of the standard for my app to run well?

```
package com.example.geoart;

public class HelloGoogleMaps2 extends MapActivity implements LocationListener {


 LocationManager locman;
  LocationListener loclis;
  Location Location;
  public  MapView map;

    List<GeoPoint> geoPointsArray = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
     private MapController controller;
    String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
   double lat;
   double lon;

 @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
initMapView();
initMyLocation();
locman = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
// locman.requestLocationUpdates(provider,60000, 100,loclis);
// Location = locman.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

 }

  /*  Find and initialize the map view. */
private void initMapView() {
map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
controller = map.getController();
map.setSatellite(false);
map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
 }

 /** Find Current Position on Map. */
  private void initMyLocation() {
  final MyLocationOverlay overlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, map);
 overlay.enableMyLocation();
//overlay.enableCompass(); // does not work in emulator
overlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Zoom in to current location
        controller.setZoom(24);
        controller.animateTo(overlay.getMyLocation());
    }
});
map.getOverlays().add(overlay);
   }

  @Override
   public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
   if (Location != null) {
    lat = Location.getLatitude();
    lon = Location.getLongitude();
    GeoPoint New_geopoint = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1e6),
            (int) (lon * 1e6));
    geoPointsArray.add(New_geopoint); //add geopoints to my array//
    controller.animateTo(New_geopoint);

     }

  }

      class MyOverlay extends Overlay {
   public MyOverlay() {
     }

       public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapv, boolean shadow) {
      super.draw(canvas, mapv, shadow);

    Projection projection = map.getProjection();
    Path p = new Path();
    for (int i = 0; i < geoPointsArray.size(); i++) {
        if (i == geoPointsArray.size() - 1) {
            break;
        }
        Point from = new Point();
        Point to = new Point();
        projection.toPixels(geoPointsArray.get(i), from);
        projection.toPixels(geoPointsArray.get(i + 1), to);
        p.moveTo(from.x, from.y);
        p.lineTo(to.x, to.y);
    }
    Paint mPaint = new Paint();

    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);

   /*mPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);*/
    super.draw(canvas, map, shadow);
}
}

    @Override
   public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

 @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }

     @Override
     public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

       @Override
       protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return false;
    }
           }
```

My main.Xml code

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <com.google.android.maps.MapView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/mapview"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:clickable="true"
 android:apiKey="AIzaSyD2epTuEtf-L_UFtQ_7vtQKQdJJ3hMA5YM"


/>
```

Comment: kindly go to `Google Map V2` becoz `Google Map V1` has deprecated. go to this: [https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

Comment: use Polyline to draw lines on the map

Comment: @Simple Plan thanks for the answer.I'm using Google Map V2 (I follwed this tutorial here https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403 very clear and simple in case someone needs the steps) any other suggestions? would truly appreciate it!